# How do I close files in python when I haven't got the file identifiers

Tags: python, file

I found myself unable to open new files in Python. When I examined with `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` I saw loads of files open for the Python process. The module I am using is apparently opening lots of files and not closing them.

I was expecting that I could close the files by deleting objects associated with the module that opened the files, but nothing happened.

I was also expecting to see the file objects somewhere in the garbage collection, but I saw nothing that resembled the open files with this:

```
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if hasattr(obj, 'read'):
        print(obj)
```

The files disappear when I quit Python.

Comment: Can I have the output of `ls`? How many files are we talking about?

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to close them through some backchannel ... it's likely a bug in the library (or how you're using it).  You should figure out where the leak is coming from and close the files appropriately.

Comment: The recommended way of opening files these days should be `with open(fname) as fid: ...`. This should (I presume) directly close the file when the `with` block is finished. Do you have a code snippet of how the library opens the files?

Comment: Yes, 'with' is a good thing, but this is in a third-party library (pytagcloud). I will look into the code on Github and file an issue if appropriate. It should be fixed in the library, but I just thought it would be faster release the file ids, rather than begin to debug another ones code. It is pytagcloud's create_tag_image that is leaky. Using the tutorial example I get lots of open files linking to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytagcloud/fonts/Lobster.ttf.

Comment: It seems to related to the pygame.font.Font object. I now discover an issue here: https://github.com/atizo/PyTagCloud/issues/6

Comment: Unless someone is telling you "give me a tag cloud or you're fired", I strongly suggest you search for "tag clouds suck". They've been talked about in the literature for 20 years, and no one has found a use for them yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that those file descriptors are leaking without being associated to Python objects. Python has no way of seeing actual file descriptors (OS resources) that are not associated with Python objects. If they were associated with Python objects, Python would close them when they are garbage collected. Alternatively, the third-party library does its own tracking of file descriptors.

You can use `os.close` on plain integers to close the associated file descriptor. If you know which file descriptors you want to keep open (usually, stdin/stdout/stderr, which are 0, 1 and 2, and maybe a few others), you can just close all other integers from 0 to 65535, or simply those in `/proc/<pid>/fd`:

```
import os

KEEP_FD = set([0, 1, 2])

for fd in os.listdir(os.path.join("/proc", str(os.getpid()), "fd")):
    if int(fd) not in KEEP_FD:
        try:
            os.close(int(fd))
        except OSError:
            pass
```

This is a pretty evil hack, though. The better solution would be to fix the third-party library.

Comment: I would say `very evil` - its not pretty at all (except maybe in its efficiency - 6 lines), but +1 for an attempt at a solution. Although really the problem is in the library being used.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes, you just do not have control over a library at all, though. Depending on the use case, trying to figure out where that library is leaking file descriptors might be close to impossible. Difficult to say without knowing which library that is. :-)

Comment: This evil hack has worked so far. In my application I added a `if os.readlink(os.path.join(pathname, fd)).endswith('ttf'):`