# Errors when trying to produce wordclouds

Tags: python

I have just installed py-game and pytagcloud in order to create a word cloud. I don't have a problem when I import the library or create the 'tags'. However, as soon as I try and render the actual image I get the following error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-4b17e94bd116>", line 1, in <module>
    create_tag_image(tags, 'cloud_large.png', size=(900, 600), fontname='Lobster')
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagcloud/__init__.py", line 344, in create_tag_image
    rectangular=rectangular)
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagcloud/__init__.py", line 275, in _draw_cloud
    tag_sprite = Tag(tag, (0, 0), fontname=fontname)
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagcloud/__init__.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.tag['size'])
OSError: unable to read font file '/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagcloud/fonts/Lobster.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1827, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1120, in get_records
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 301, in wrapped
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 346, in _fixed_getinnerframes
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 1453, in getinnerframes
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 1410, in getframeinfo
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 672, in getsourcefile
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 701, in getmodule
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 685, in getabsfile
  File "/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 361, in abspath
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.
```

I had absolutely no idea what this meant so I naturally took the 'simple' course of action of trying to use a totally different word cloud library. This is where I came across 'wordcloud'. Interestingly, when I try to import this module I get pretty much the same error- have I installed the libraries incorrectly or something?

Any assistance would be great appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What's in `'/Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagcloud/fonts/Lobster.ttf'`?

Comment: I can get as far as /Users/harry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytagclou‌​d/fonts - then it says 'Lobster.ttf is not a directory. I guess it's some sort of binary file?

Comment: It's a file, namely a font. Is it located in the directory?

Comment: Yep, it's located in that directory. Along with various other font files.

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/atizo/PyTagCloud/issues/6), I got "The problem seems to be too many open files. As `create_tag_image` is called again and again the number of font file references increases. I believe it is around 1000 open files that I run into troubles." Not sure if it helps, but if you can change the number of files you open at once, that might help. There is an _evil_ workaround suggested there, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944211/how-do-i-close-files-in-python-when-i-havent-got-the-file-identifiers).

Comment: I'll take a look now. Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated!